# How to replace first number from each line of a ".txt" file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, replace

[check out this image for sample .txt file where on each line of this file i want to replace 0 with 1 also i want to save the file with same name..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5sQq.png)

How to replace first number from each line of a .txt file from a folder which has multiples of .txt file in python . also i want to keep the same filename after replacing.

```
my code:-
```

this code is working and giving me desired result. Can someone suggest a simpler approach

```html
import os 
def process_line_item(x):
    index = x[0]
    line_str = x[1]
    new_first_value = [str(1)]
    return ' '.join(new_first_value + x[1].split(' ')[1:])
    
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        data = None
        with open('{}' .format(filename), 'r') as file:
            data = file.read() 
            new_data = '\n'.join(list(map(process_line_item, enumerate(data.split('\n')))))
            with open('{}' .format(filename), 'w') as file_out:
                file_out.write(new_data)
```

Comment: Are the files size too big?

Comment: No, in my folder there are 200 file in which 100jpeg and 100txt file. so all .txt file have cordinates of images of respective .jpeg file.

Comment: i just want to replace first number 0 from each line of txt file. and same thing for all 100 txt file without changing the name of txt files

Comment: please check out the image link which i have given on my question

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import re

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        with open('{}'.format(filename), 'r+') as file:
            data = file.read()
            new_data = re.sub(r'^0','1',data,flags=re.MULTILINE) 
            file.seek(0)
            file.truncate() 
            file.write(new_data)
            file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
            with open('{}' .format(filename), 'r+') as file:
                lines = file.readlines()
                file.seek(0, 0) #set the pointer to 0,0 cordinate of file
                for line in lines:
                    row = line.strip().split(" ")

                    if not int(row[0]):
                        row[0] = '1'
                        print(row)
                        file.write(" ".join(row) + "\n")
```

I think code is pretty straightforward, but if you want me to explain please let me know.

Comment: it has worked randomly. some of the files got replaced with 1 and some didn't. also it showed error at :-      if not int(row[0]):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Comment: ok, can you please paste a sample of the file which is not converted. This code assumes there is no space before 0 in all the rows of all the files and each row in the file must start with 0 not even with 0.0

Comment: @Shubham-Singh This error '''if not int(row[0]): ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10'''' will show up when row doesn't start with 0. May be some space is there.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs -I{} sed -i '' 's/0/1/' {}
```

**Detailed:**

Steps:

1. Find all the target files: `find . -type f -name "*.txt"`.
2. `sed` is a swiss knife to replace string for your specified file, the regex parameter `'s/0/1/'` matches the first occurrence `0` and replace it with `1`, as you wish, `-i ''` means overriding the original file.
3. `xargs` used to parse the file result into every single file and pass it to `sed` as stdin recursively.

Done! `shell` commands do these kinds of tasks great!

BTW, welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Just a correction to @Itachi 's answer which worked for me.

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs -I{} sed -i 's/0/1/' {}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use "r+" to open the file to read and write in one go.

```
import os


def process_line_item(x):
    index = x[0]
    line_str = x[1]
    new_first_value = [str(1)]
    return ' '.join(new_first_value + x[1].split(' ')[1:])


for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        data = None
        with open('{}'.format(filename), 'r+') as file:
            data = file.read()
            new_data = '\n'.join(list(map(process_line_item, enumerate(data.split('\n')))))
            file.write(new_data)
```

Comment: it just combines opening the file in one statement

Comment: your code is fine but it has one issue, instead of overwriting my file it has concatenated the new previous result with new one.      for ex:-  0 1.2 1.3 3.4 4.5 it should be changed to 1 1.2 1.3 3.4 4.5 but your code is keeping the previous value and on new line writing the desired result.